# Dynamic updates in social networking webpages

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, social-networking, auto-update

I am creating a social networking site using php,jQuery and MySQL. I have a big doubt.  How to dynamically update a user's home page when one of his/her friends does an action and if that has to appear on current user's page as soon as the friend has updated.  I am new to this, please help me in this problem?

Comment: I think this would be useful to you.   `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283007/problem-with-creating-chat-room-application`

Comment: i was searching for some time . i found that setinterval() helps to query the database at regular intervals and load the data at the place i need . but i guess there must be some better way . could someone help me

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking for a way to implement push functionality from your web server to a current user's page.

The push data will be sent as part of a friends' action or soon after (in a queued fashion), and once it arrives to the client Javascript should be used to update the view.

Some methods of doing that are described on the [push technologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#HTTP_server_push) Wikipedia page.

Comment: dont mind if its silly . my question is, in server push mechanism too does the client constantly keep querying the database and loads new data if it finds any changes or is it something else?

Comment: This is the difference between pull and push... In pull mode, the client queries regularly. In push, the client has an open channel to the server and the server sends data only when there is an update.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a JavaScript timer function in web page side. And regularly to check whether new information is gather.
If there is information, then add new information in the page or notice user.

This is a [jQuery Timer](http://jquery.offput.ca/timers/).

This is function of [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). You can use this function in jQuery Timer to check whether there have new information.

If there have new content, you can use "Adding elements to the DOM" to display them out. This is a reference for this topic, [Adding elements to the DOM](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml).

I think this way would be helpful.

Comment: this is fine but one doubt, so once in the time interval it will query the database . it will surely be a server overload isn't it?

Comment: Sure, server overload need to be consider. You can create a table in database to recode whether a new event is raised, if yes, then query detail information from other tables. Or, even, you can use Redis or other NOSQL instance to performance those cache data query.